# ng-slider e.settings.value is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to us the ng-slider npm module which can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-slider

I have imported all the necessary JS code. Then used this to make the slider:

```
<input slider id="sliderID" ng-model="value" name="slider" type="text" options="{from:0,to:100,step:1,smooth:false,skin:'plastic'}"/>
```

It appears on screen however it does not work as I getting an error in ng-slider.min.js. which is as follows:

```
   "Error: e.settings.value is undefined
   e.prototype.create@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:9226
   e.prototype.init@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:8818
   e@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:8300
   .link/p@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:2268
   .link/m@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:1420
   .link/</<@http://lh:5000/javascripts/ng-slider.min.js:6:2089
   timeout/timeoutId<@http://lh:5000/javascripts/angular.js:16299:28
   completeOutstandingRequest@http://lh:5000/javascripts/angular.js:4924:7
   Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://lh:5000/javascripts/angular.js:5312:7
```

So naturally I looked into the ng-slider.min.js file but of course as its minified it was really nigh on impossible to see what "e" was and why its setting value wasn't defined. Therefore if anyone has come across this error before and knows how to fix it that would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Adam

EDIT: The two ids on the html was erroneous, corrected now but the original problem still exists.

Comment: Never worked on it before, but can you try assigning something to value like `$scope.value="11"`?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see is you have **TWO** IDs of your `input`. Omit one of them.

```
<input slider id="sliderID" ng-model="value" name="slider" type="text" options="{from:0,to:100,step:1,smooth:false,skin:'plastic'}"/>
```

Comment: Ah yes, the issue actually appeared before i added the second ID (not a moron just completely forgot I'd put one on in the first place *facepalm* I have removed the second ID and it still has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<input slider id="sliderID" ng-model="value" name="slider" type="text" options="myOptions"/>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.myOptions = {from: 0, to: 100, step: 1, smooth: false, skin: 'plastic'};
```

`myOptions` is a scope not a regular object when you pass in the options attribute.

PS: And remove the 2nd id as @Zee said.

EDIT: You probably forgot to add `$scope.value`  to the controller.

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this and the problem still persists.

Comment: did you add `$scope.value=3` (for example) to the controller?